# Javascript, regex, keep numerical part from string, including decimal place

Tags: javascript

I need to parse some data that contains comma formatted numbers and text like this, keeping only numerical part:

"The stock is 1,124 units"

I came up with this regex that is working great, except for numbers under 0, example a price that could be 0,259 EUR

```
qty = qty.textContent.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

How can I modify for removing only text, but still keeping the sense of original number

I'd like -> 0.259
Not -> 0259

EDITED

I need both situations, thousands separator and decimal place.

Depending on parse, could be USD when comma is thousands separator, or EUR, where dot is decimal place. I will make a switch case for currency and thank you for your fast answers!

Comment: Ok, so that comma is a thousands separator and not a decimal separator, right? Is there any other punctuation in the original string?

Comment: see edited, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as there are no periods in the string overwise, then this should work:

```
qty = qty.textContent.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
```

If there is (or might be) other periods, then it gets a little more tricky.

You might try something like:

```
([^\d.]|\.(?!\d))
```

This will match characters that aren't numeric digits or periods, or periods that aren't followed by another digit. So something like this should work:

```
"The st.oc.k is 1,124.22 units.".replace(/([^\d.]|\.(?!\d))/g,"")
```

Gives you back: `1124.22`

Comment: I accepted yours because it's working, however, I use /[^\d\.,]/g then replace comma if USD. Thank you Matt!

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work

```
\d+(\,|\.)\d+
```

It matches both 1,230 and 0.123

If you want to remove the comma you can do this

```
yourstr.replace(",", "");
```

Comment: I believe the original intent was to remove the comma. Although the question isn't exactly clear, but that's what the OP's original does.

Comment: I need both, sorry for confusion